# Control a subform from main form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a main form `Form_frmSale`and it contain a sub-form `frmSale_subform`.How can I "access" the fields in subform

For e.g with no subform i would do `Sale_Date.Enabled = True`

What code should i put if i want to control subform fields from main form(Suppose `Sale_Date`is in a subform

I tried the following but its not working

```vb
Me.frmSale_subform.Sale_Date.Enabled = True

frmSale_subform.Sale_Date.Enabled = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you should be able to do that is using:

```vb
Me.frmSale_subform.Controls("Sale_Date").Enabled = True
```

If that doesn't suite your fancy you can also reference http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm for other ways to do it.

Comment: No problem.  I found learning how to reference objects in Access was one of the hardest things to learn how to do.